# Checkbox not Displaying in IE browser in ItextPDF

Tags: java, internet-explorer, itext, itextpdf

I am not able to get some checkboxes displayed in IE browser while it is working fine in Chrome browser.The code I used is as follows:

```
rect = new Rectangle(185, 798 - i * 20, 200, 788 - i * 20);
    rect.setRight(r);
    rect.setLeft(l);

    checkbox = new RadioCheckField(writer, rect, "Check-Box_" + descid + "_1", "Yes");
    checkbox.setCheckType(RadioCheckField.TYPE_CHECK);
    checkbox.setBorderColor(BaseColor.BLACK);
    checkbox.setBorderWidth(1);
    field = checkbox.getCheckField();
    writer.addAnnotation(field);
```

[image]

Comment: The code is correct, the PDF viewer in IE browser probably doesn't support either form fields or widget annotations.

Comment: But some checkboxes are displaying at particular positions and some are not as i am incrementing 'i' value while creating rectangle...!

Comment: That's strange. Can you share the PDF? Can you share a screen shot (maybe the check boxes are covered by a blue area)? Also: which PDF viewer is embedded in MSIE? Is it Adobe Reader?

Comment: the above image is downloaded pdf from MSIE.Check boxes missing at circled areas

Comment: Hmm... That's indeed a mystery. I assume that you're using similar code for all check boxes, and I have no idea why that code works for one set of check boxes, but not for another set. Can you share the PDF?

Comment: I had uploaded total PDF in the above link..After uploading all checkboxes are displaying..But while downloading the attachment from MSIE some checkboxes are missing...Strange..!